# Парсинг своего веб-приложения в Xml и Excel файлы

Tags: asp.net-core

В моём веб приложении есть три странички на который списки employees, tasks, projects каким образом можно выгрузить каждый список в xml и excel документы.
Нужно именно парсить страничку или можно с базы данных взять эти файлы и выгрузить в xml excel
(ASP.NET.CORE)

Comment: Зачем парсить страницы, если есть доступ к базе данных? Формируйте необходимый формат данных и выгружайте.

Comment: ну окей они у меня есть(данные) с помощью чего я должен их записать в excel/xml?

Comment: есть Open XML SDK или EPPlus.Core